# Convert array of Class[] to a different class of type List<different class>

Tags: java, arrays, class, types

How do I convert an array of a type of class to a different type of class when all the elements match?

```
List<ClaimBean> claimBean = new ArrayList<ClaimBean>(Arrays.asList(claims));
NewClaimBean[] inArray = inbetween.toArray(new NewClaimBean[claimBean.size()]);
```

This throws an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: what do you mean: "when all the elements match"?

Comment: If the thing that you need to work with are `NewClaimBean`s, then you should ask for a list of `NewClaimBean`s. Taking one type as a parameter and then secretly working with a more specific subtype is very strongly indicative of a flawed design.

Comment: BTW, you just did what (I guess) you're asking. But all elements don't match (i.e. at least one is not an instance of NewClaimBean), hence the exception you get.

Comment: To get better help sooner please provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) along with full error message. There are few things we would need to know like relation between classes, and actual content of your list/array.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your problem.